# PHP Form Check Boxes

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am creating a form where the user sets access levels to usernames in the database, the form shows a check box and the username.

This is the form below. It is populated using the database.

```
<?php
require '../Pages/Database Actions/Database_Connect.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$row_num = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo '<table class="setuseraccess_title"><tr><td class="comitttiemembers_title"><h3 align="center">User Access Levels</h3></td></tr></table><br />';
echo'<form class="setuseraccess" action="index.php?page=member-profile" method="post"><table>';

for ($val = 0; $val < $row_num; $val++)
{
    echo '<tr><td><input type=\'checkbox\' name=\'SetAccess\' value=\''.$row['username'].'\' /></td>
        <td>'.$row['username'].'</td><td>'.$row['accesslevel'].'</td></tr>';
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

echo '<tr><td colspan="3"><br /><select name="useraccesslevel">
<option value="0">Access Level 0</option>
<option value="1">Access Level 1</option>
<option value="2">Access Level 2</option>
<option value="3">Access Level 3</option>
<option value="4">Access Level 4</option>
<option value="5">Access Level 5</option>
</select><br /></td></tr>';
echo'<tr><td colspan="3"><br /><input class="member-buttons" type="submit" name="mb" value="Set Access" /><br /></td></tr></table></form>';
?>
```

How would i go about updating the access levels of the users in the database? also im not sure if my checkbox value should be the players username. what would be the best way of doing this?

-Edit-
Sorry forgot to put the action page.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['useraccesslevel']))
{
    $Alevel = trim($_POST['useraccesslevel']);
    echo $Alevel;

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $row_num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    for ($val = 0; $val < $row_num; $val++)
    {
        if(isset($_POST[$row['username']]))
        {
            $sql="UPDATE `wohsa`.`members` SET `accesslevel` = '" + $Alevel + "' WHERE `members`.`username` = '" + $_POST[$row['username']] + "';";
            $result1=mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

that is the action page where i attempt to update the values in the database

----EDIT 2----
I have done it, and it works well! Thanks to dianuj who got me in the right place :)

Comment: with an update query, what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: updated question with the action page

Comment: What goes wrong with what you have already coded? Is there an error?

Comment: no it doesnt update the access levels with no errors or output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to correct the name of `checkbox` to an `array` of `checbox`

```
 for ($val = 0; $val < $row_num; $val++)
 {
echo '<tr><td><input type=\'checkbox\' name=\'SetAccess[]\' value=\''.$row['username'].'\' /></td>
    <td>'.$row['username'].'</td><td>'.$row['accesslevel'].'</td></tr>';
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

when you submit the `form` you have access the values or ids of each use in `$_REQUEST[SetAcces][index]` and run your `update` query in loop to the length of `$_REQUEST[SetAcces][index]`

```
update table set role..... where userid ='your $_REQUEST value'
```

not a full functional but to give an idea
hope this helps

Comment: i have not used request and arrays like this before and im not quite sure how to to get the checkboxes using it ad how to get the length of it

Comment: there you have to work :) dear we are here to help but feeding totaly will have a bad impact to you , you have little struggle its not a big task but if you done this by yourself then in future you will not face these problems have fun cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['mb'])){

$usernames = array();
foreach($_POST['SetAccess'] as $key=>$value)
$usernames[] = "'".$value."'";

$accesslevel = $_POST['useraccesslevel']

mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `accesslevel` = '".$accesslevel."' WHERE `username` IN (".implode(",",$usernames).")");


}
?>
```

You can add your own additional verifications and filtering.

Comment: Let's start with the fact that this is a textbook SQL injection vulnerability and you should never do it unless you want your site hacked.

Comment: at the moment it is behind closed doors, it will have prequations to prevent that before i put it online